# Where to ask a question about whether US credit reports can distinguish between a citizen and a non-citizen with SSN

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Just like what the title says. I want to know whether one can tell if someone is a US citizen/permanent resident or not just by looking at their credit report. It's easy if the person is an international without an SSN; however, it's not uncommon for an international student to have a State ID and an established credit history. In that case, I cannot seem to find a way to prove if he/she is an international student just by looking at the credit reports.

So I would appreciate if somebody can point to a place where I can find a definite answer to this stipulation. Note that I have done an extensive google search on this and nothing helpful came up.

Comment: Have you looked at [money.se]? They have a [credit-report](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-report) tag.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a moment to think about it, I think there may not be a site in the Stack Exchange network suitable to your question. But more importantly, why do you even need an answer to this question? Frankly, it feels like you have [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

With that being said, my first and still best thought was [the Personal Finance & Money site](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), because you're looking at credit reports. Now, your question isn't really what they're about, because it doesn't seem to be about personal finance, but they still may have the expertise you're looking for.

I also considered [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/), and [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), but none of those really feel right.

Comment: Yes, I also had a feeling that this question is appropriate for none of the Stack Exchange sites. As for why I want to know the answer is simple - if it is indeed the way I suspected, then that will simplify some things greatly.